# Find the taylor expansion of $\sin(x+1)\sin(x+2)$ at $x_0=-1$, up to order $5$.

Tags: taylor-expansion

Find the taylor expansion of $\sin(x+1)\sin(x+2)$ at $x_0=-1$, up to order $5$.

**Taylor Series**

$$f(x)=f(a)+(x-a)f'(a)+\frac{(x-a)^2}{2!}f''(a)+...+\frac{(x-a)^r}{r!}f^{(r)}(a)+...$$

I've got my first term...

$f(a) = \sin(-1+1)\sin(-1+2)=\sin(0)\sin(1)=0$

Now, I've calculated $f'(x)=\sin(x+1)\cos(x+2)+\sin(x+2)\cos(x+1)$

So that $f'(-1) = \sin(1) = 0.8414709848$

This means my second term would be $(x+1)(0.8414709848).$

But, this doesn't seem to be nice and neat like the other expansions I have done and I can't figure out what I've done wrong.

Merry Christmas and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did nothing wrong. However, building the Taylor series for each term is better and easier.

Also, using the decimal is not good. Keep using $\sin(1).$

Also, notice that actually $\sin(1)\not =0.8414709848$. This is only an approximate value.

Comment: Aren't I already building the Taylor Series for each term? I started with the first, then the next etc.?

Comment: Well, I don't. but this is not so difficult, is it?

Comment: You said "However, building the Taylor series for each term is better and easier". Isn't that what I'm doing?

Comment: No. What I said is building the Taylor series for each of $\sin(x+1)$, and $\sin(x+2)$.

Comment: And then multiply them together?

Comment: That's right with ignoring terms $(x+1)^k$ with $k\gt5.$

Comment: I've got both Taylor series for sin(x+1) and sin(x+2)... But multiplying them together? Is there an easier way?

Comment: Well, this is not so complicated. If you want to know an easier way, you can see other's answer which has a good idea I don't notice.

Answer (score 4):

**HINT**

Build the Taylor series for each term up to order 5 and multiply them, ignoring terms $(x+1)^m $with $m > 5$.

Leave coefficients $\cos(1)$ and $\sin(1)$, without computing them.

I suppose you are able to continue from here. If not, just post. Merry Xmas.

Comment: Thanks, but do I need to keep differentiating? The product rule is getting quite long a laborious now... :/

Comment: @MrCroutini. You only need to differentiate one sine at the time. But there is another way : replace Sin[x+1] Sin[x+2] by (Cos[1]-Cos[2x+3])/2 ... assuming that I remember my trig identities !

Comment: @Daniel Rust. Thanks for editing. I am almost blind and I do not "see" what I type. Beside plain ASCII and at my ages, everything is now difficult. Merry Xmas.

Comment: I'd like to take the credit but it was actually Mr Croutini that edited the page - I just fixed one small typo in his edit.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$f′(x)=\sin(x+1)\cos(x+2)+\sin(x+2)\cos(x+1) = \sin(2x+3).$

Comment: Good remark indeed; this makes the problem much simpler !

Answer (score 0):

use  this formula
$\sin(a)\sin(b)=1/2(cos(a-b)-cos(a+b))$

Comment: Please rectify the left hand side (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html)